# Disabling Pycharm "Unresolved references" inspection for attribute names but not for variable names?

Tags: pycharm

I would like to preserve the red underlines for unresolved variable names in scopes, which is an inspection that works well and brings up the option to import the name. However I want to disable the warnings for unresolved attributes (e.g. x.y), which is not a reliable inspection due to metaprogramming. These settings appear coupled, which seems rather unfortunate. Is there a workaround or am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible for warnings about all attributes at the moment. You can send a feature request to the [PyCharm's issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY).

You can disable the unresolved references for a particular class explicitly by decorating it with any custom decorator:

```
@any_decorator
class C:
    ...
```

or by putting `@DynamicAttrs` inside the docstring of the class:

```
class C:
    """...

    @DynamicAttrs
    """
    ...
```

or you can do it implicitly by using "Alt+Enter" on the problematic attribute and selecting "Mark all attributes of C as ignored".